# Addresses in paths of State Patricia Trie

Tags: addresses, merkle-patricia-tries, block-header

Every block header has 3 patricia trees. In State Patricia Trie, the paths are the sha3 of the ethereum addresses, and the value for any particular address is encoded with RLP.

But, what addresses are in the paths of the State Patricia Trie of a given block? All Ethereum addresses or only those mentioned in the transactions of that particular blocks?

I hope I was clear enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every block header has 3 patricia trees.

It contains a hash of the *root* nodes of 3 tries, not the entire tries. The tries themselves aren't stored in the block, they're stored separately in the state data. When a new block is received by a given node in the network, it applies the state transitions described in the block's transactions, and updates its locally stored state data accordingly. The hash of the root of its local tries should match the field in the block header.

> But, what addresses are in the paths of the State Patricia Trie of a given block? All Ethereum addresses or only those mentioned in the transactions of that particular blocks?

The hash of the root node of the "world" state - i.e. the combined state associated with *all* addresses, as organised into a single trie - will change if there is a change to the state associated with any *single* address.

So regardless of the number of transactions included in a block, the hash of the root of the entire state trie will change.